# Where does 'font-size: 13.333333969116211px' come from?

Tags: php, html, css, ckeditor

We use CKEditor in our application for letting users edit certain e-mail templates, but for some reason, many of these templates end up with `p`- and `span`-tags with annoying text styles:

```
<p style="font-size: 13.333333969116211px;">
```

Or with line-height:

```
<span style="font-size: 13.333333969116211px; line-height: 1.231em;">
```

Our customers complain that their e-mails come out with weird text styles and make very clear that they did not manually add those styles (which makes sense).

The strange thing is: once we save the template ourselves using the same editor, those weird styles disappear from the source HTML (in the database). Then after a while, all those styles slip back in there - presumably when customers (re)use our editor.

We decided to Google that exact string, `font-size: 13.333333969116211px`, and - to our surprise - [found 80.000 completely unrelated results](https://www.google.nl/#q=font-size:+13.333333969116211px). The font-size value is obviously created by some sort of calculation (100 / 7.5), but I have no clue where to look.

Does anyone know where these strings originate from and how we get rid of them?

Comment: 100 sounds like a DPI value :)

Comment: Ckeditor... which version? Oo

Comment: Which version of CKEditor do you use? This is a Chrome's and Safari's bug which for which a fix was added around CKEditor 4.3-4.4.

Comment: We are using 4.3.3. Interesting.

Comment: See http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=226941 and https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=114791.

According to the [changelog](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/CHANGES.md) patches were introduced in 4.4.1 and 4.4.2.

Comment: Ah, perfect! Would you add that as an answer?

Comment: I don't get why this question got a downvote. It's well-documented, well-explained, we tried what we could, we googled, we searched on SO ... Really annoying sometimes.

Comment: Unfortunately, somebody just has to be that guy every now and then.

Comment: @Sherlock: I added an answer with some more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These ugly `<span>` tags and even uglier inline styles are created by the native implementation of <kbd>backspace</kbd> / <kbd>delete</kbd> in Blink and Webkit based browsers. They can also appear when copying and pasting content or drag and dropping.

Nearly two years ago I reported the problems with <kbd>backspace</kbd> and <kbd>delete</kbd> here:

- https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=226941
- https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=114791

We believed that with support from the users that we had (I don't know anyone who likes the current behaviour), we will be able to convince browser vendors to change this behaviour (which by them may unfortunately be expected). So we waited, I believe one year, but we didn't even got an answer whether this is an expected behaviour and whether there's any chance to have it fixed some day.

Therefore, in CKEditor 4.4.1 and 4.4.2 we shipped patches for most common problems with <kbd>backspace</kbd> and <kbd>delete</kbd>. Also, CKEditor handles copy and paste in a custom way, so if the [Advanced Content Filter](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_acf) is enabled, then most of the crappy HTML mess will be filtered out.

The remaining piece is a custom handling for drag and drop which we are working on in [CKEditor 4.5.0](http://dev.ckeditor.com/query?group=status&milestone=CKEditor+4.5.0). It will be released at the beginning of 2015.